# Which of the following expressions can be used to calculate the slope of the line tangent to the function $y=1/x^2$ at $x=3$

Tags: calculus

So I am preparing for my teaching license test and need some help reviewing some simple calculus. I haven't seen it for awhile so this is where I am at. I know that $ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ is one way you could find the slope of a tangent line but I am having trouble remembering how to use that in this situation. I am thinking that it is either A or C because of the 1/9 but that is as far as I have gotten and any help with reasoning would be awesome. Thank you

> A. $ \lim_{x\to 3} \frac{(1/x^2-1/9)}{x-3}$
>
> B. $ \lim_{x\to 3} \frac{(1/x^2-1/3)}{x-3}$
>
> C. $ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1/x^2-1/9)}{x}$
>
> D. $ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1/x^2-1/3)}{x}$

Comment: Try $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to x}\frac{f(h)-f(x)}{h-x}$$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is A. The derivative of a function $f(x)$ at a point $a$ is defined as
$$ f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} $$
which is equivalent to 
$$ f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} $$
We can get the second formula by substitution. Let $h=x-a$, then $x=a+h$ and as $x\to a$, $h\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

it is after the formula $$\lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x \to 3}\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{9}}{x-3}$$

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is A. The slope of a tangent line to a curve is given by: $$lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ Your initial point is given: $$P_1(3,f(3))  \rightarrow  P_1(3, \frac{1}{9})$$ Your second point is: $$P_2(3+h,f(3+h))  \rightarrow  P_2(3+h, \frac{1}{(3+h)^2})$$ Using the initial formula stated, we get:$$lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{3+h-3} \rightarrow lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{(3+h)^2}-\frac{1}{9}}{h}$$ by making a change of varibles, where $$x=h+3 \rightarrow h=x-3$$ we can write the limit as: $$lim_{x\to 3} \frac{\frac{1}{(3+x-3)^2}-\frac{1}{9}}{x-3} \rightarrow lim_{x\to 3} \frac{\frac{1}{(x)^2}-\frac{1}{9}}{x-3} $$ Also, NOTE that answer A is the only one that presents an indeterminate form of 0/0. This must happen when you are trying to find slopes of tangent lines to curves.